# Como hago en C# para que en un array aleatorio, sumen los pares y multipliquen los impares? Discriminando al cero

Tags: c#, array, bucle-for, condiciones, random

Creo haberlo hecho de manera correcta (al menos a la vista) pero al ejecutar, el algoritmo solo se queda con el primer par, o el primer impar y me arroja ese mismo numero como resultado. Aquí va el código:

```
int[] vector = new int[6];
Random x = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    vector[i] = x.Next(0, 20);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   Console.Write(vector[i] + " ");
   Console.Write("");
}
    
int suma = 0;
int Multi = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{     
    if (vector[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        suma = vector[i] + suma;
    }
    else
    {
        Multi = vector[i] * Multi;
    }
}
                    
Console.WriteLine("La suma es:" + suma);                       
Console.WriteLine("La multi es: " + Multi);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Hola podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles y marcar como acepatada la que mas te haya gustado, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Bueno veo que el ejercicio está casi "correcto" aunque has puesto el código con un poco de lío con las llaves. Depurado el código sería el siguiente:

```
int[] vector = new int[6];
Random x = new Random();
// Obtiene el array e imprime el mismo usando un único bucle
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   vector[i] = x.Next(0, 20);
   Console.Write(vector[i] + " ");
   Console.Write("");
}
// Se procede a sumar los pares y multiplicar los impares.   
int suma = 0;
int Multi = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
     if (vector[i] % 2 == 0)
     {
        suma = vector[i] + suma;
     }
     else
     {
        Multi = vector[i] * Multi;
     }
 }
 // Por último devolvemos los resultados
 Console.WriteLine("La suma es:" + suma);
 Console.WriteLine("La multi es: " + Multi);
                
 Console.ReadKey();
```

El caso para discriminar el cero no hay que tenerlo en cuenta ya que cuando hacemos la operación módulo dos ( .. % 2) entra en los pares y al sumar no afecta al resultado.
Has de poner cuidado con el tema de las llaves porque puedes liarla mucho, el resultado lo damos ya fuera del bucle. El bucle nos sirve para calcular los datos y ya luego los mostramos.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sumatoria = 0;
int productoria = 1;

foreach (int n in vector)
{
    if (n % 2 == 0) //pares
    {
        sumatoria += n;
    }
    else //impares
    {
        productoria *= n;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Sumatoria: {0}", sumatoria);
    Console.WriteLine("Productoria: {0}", productoria);
}
```

Se declara la **variable sumatoria** para sumar los números pares y la **variable productoria** para multiplicar los números impares, posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo foreach** que irá recorriendo todos los elementos del arreglo, preguntando si son pares o impares y haciendo la operaciones correspondientes. Finalmente se imprimen los resultados obtenidos.

Si quieres ahorrarte código puedes hacer uso de **Linq**:

```
int sum = vector.Where(n % 2 == 0).Sum(); // suma los pares
int productoria = vector.Where(n % 2 == 1).Aggregate((a, b) => a * b); //multiplica los impares
```

Pare hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Esta solución está un poco mejor que otras, al menos está el intento de respetar el esfuerzo inicial de OP; sin embargo, sufre de los mismos síntomas, en ningún momento le dice a OP por qué no está obteniendo el resultado que espera.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es complicado de más y difícil de leer y razonar (de ahí que sea propenso a errores, como has visto), mejor usa LinQ:

```
var r = new Random();

// Generamos 10 números aleatorios entre el 0 y el 20
var numeros = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).Select(_ => r.Next(0, 20));
// Creamos una secuencia con con los pares que no sean cero.
var pares = numeros.Where(n => (n != 0) && ((n % 2) == 0));
// Creamos una secuencia con los impares que no sean cero.
var impares = numeros.Where(n => (n != 0) && ((n % 2) != 0));

Console.WriteLine($"Los numeros son: {String.Join(", ", numeros)}");
// Usamos Aggregate para sumar todos los valores
Console.WriteLine($"La suma de los pares es: {pares.Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a + b)}");
// Usamos Aggregate para multiplicar todos los valores
Console.WriteLine($"La multiplicacion de los impares es: {impares.Aggregate(1, (a, b) => a * b)}");
```

Las ventajas que ofrece el código anterior respecto al que presentaste son:

- Es notablemente más corto, con lo que facilita su lectura y comprensión (además de tener menos oportunidades de contener errores).
- La evaluación de las secuencias LinQ es [perezosa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluaci%C3%B3n_perezosa), lo que hace que el coste de ejecución del programa sea menor al ejecutar menos instrucciones y ejecutarlas sólo cuando es neceario.

Comment: Entonces, la solución es arreglarle el ejercicio, sin explicarle dónde está su error, y proponer una estructura completamente diferente a la que OP tenía al principio? Suena a *"no me funciona esto en php"*, y la respuesta:  *"Deja PHP, mejor hazlo así en C#"*. Hay mucho que mejorar en estas respuesta.

Comment: Tienes razón en que no he explicado dónde tiene el fallo el autor de la pregunta. No tienes razón al mencionar que he presentado una solución en un lenguaje diferente. La respuesta que di es tan C# como la pregunta realizada.

Comment: Acepto tu observación:  no presentaste la solución en un lenguaje diferente. Permíteme hacer una enmienda a mi propia observación. Ofreciste un camino MUY diferente al que OP estaba intentando en primera instancia.

Comment: @Arriel ¿Por qué presentar una solución diferente a la que el *OP* intenta es reprochable?

Comment: No es reprochable en sí mismo, y lamento sea la impresión que mi comentario te dejó. Mira la pregunta: Un ejercicio acerca de ciclos y acumuladores. Es claramente un ejercicio de *Introducción a la Programación*, o tal vez *Programación I*. Introducir Linq sólo lleva a más confusión. OP no quería *one liners*. OP buscaba ayuda para entender por qué su algoritmo no daba el resultado que esperaba.

Comment: Como usuario de esta página, considero que ofrecer alternativas modernas a incluso las preguntas más simples es la manera de responder. Si nos limitamos a responder con un código que podría haberse generado hace 20 años no conseguiremos que las nuevas generaciones aprendan nada nuevo ni haremos avanzar el lenguaje o su uso. Dicho eso, el código con el que respondí no es extremadamente complejo ni lejos del alcance de nuevos programadores, debemos perder el miedo a usar las herramientas que el propio lenguaje ofrece.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con ofrecer alternativas más modernas. Es preferible utilizar los beneficios de las versiones nuevas del lenguaje; sin embargo, en términos de enseñanza-aprendizaje se va de lo simple a lo complejo, no al contrario. OP está aprendiendo lo simple. No es cuestión de miedo. Es una estrategia. En fin, este hilo no va a ningún lado. Saludos.

Comment: @Arriel las respuestas que se dan a esta pregunta no son solo para el OP, sino para cualquiera que tenga un problema similar, por eso no esta nada mal usar Linq, alomejor otro usuario con un problema similar esta interesado en resolver su problema usando Linq, aqui las respuestas se dan para todos no para un individuo

Comment: @Arriel LinQ no tiene nada de complejo, lo que lo hace complejo a ojos de los usuarios nuevos es, precisamente, señalarlo (inadecuadamente) como complejo.